# PowerShell script deployment from Intune

Tags: powershell, intune

I'have a simple task - add users into the local administrators group.
We have an Azure AD and using Intune to manage users and computers.
I have a script that I'm going to deploy via Intune:

```
$String = [System.Environment]::UserName
$String = -join ($String -csplit "([A-Z])")[1..3]
$email = $String+ "@somedomain.com"
Net localgroup administrators "AzureAD\$email" /add
```

The first three rows make a current user's email address that should be in format firstname+lastnameinitial@somedomain.com e.g. joed@somedomain.com for Joe Dow

Here is an issue, $email variable in the right format, but the script failed while deploying it, BUT, if I type email explicitly in the last row like:
Net localgroup administrators "AzureAD\joed@somedomain.com" /add
it works.
What I missed
Appreciate any help
Thanks,
Mat

Comment: You mention `Joe Dow` as an example: if your usernames have spaces in them, `-join ($String -csplit "([A-Z])")[1..3]` won't work as intended. Do they really have spaces?

Comment: No, there are no spaces. $email variable is in the correct format, but something doesn't work